# Firefox add-on sdk if failing AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon-sdk

Please note the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: loginURL,
     data: jsonArray,
     async: true,
     success: function(data, status){
         alert(status);
     },
     error: function(data, status){
         alert(status + " 1");
     }
});
```

The error case is thrown every time, but I have fiddler open and I'm receiving data from the server just fine. I'm attaching a panel to a widget. In the HTML that gets loaded in the panel, I'm including the latest jquery and a login javascript file.

Comment: Also, this same code works in the Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[EDIT: I updated the link]*

Is this in a content script? Content scripts cannot make cross-domain requests currently ( chrome extensions I think can ). What you *can* do instead is make the request in main.js using the request module:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html

As of SDK version 1.12 ( to be released in 6 weeks ) you *will* be able to make cross-domain requests in content scripts, making this sort of functionality a bit simpler to implement.

Comment: Thank you. I'm passing a message to the main request page and passing the response back to the content script. It's a little much, but it works.

Comment: Old link is broken and updated. please check if that is correct.

Comment: The second answer to this question is more up to date.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can make cross domain request in content script of Firefox extension. check this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts

you need to clarify the domain permission in package.json like this:

```
"permissions": {
  "cross-domain-content": ["http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk"]
}
```